# Progress bar loading in Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am working on an Android application in which I am sending and receiving some data from parse.com server. Now I want to apply progress bar on any of my method which involves any sending and receiving of data for example at the time of login I want to put progress bar with percentage, when percentage completed to 100, progress bar should be dismiss.

My code is given below:

```
public void login(){        
            showLoadingDialog(); // <===Progress Bar should start here 

            ParseUser.logInInBackground(email, password,
                    new LogInCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {

                        dismissLoadingDialog();// <===Progress Bar should end here

                        if (user != null) {
                            showMessage("Logged In!");
                            user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                            CURRENT_USER = user;

                        try{    
                            CURRENT_USER.getParseObject("infor").fetchIfNeededInBackground(
                            new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            public void done(ParseObject curreno,ParseException e) {
                            if(e==null){
                            if (currentUserinfo == null) {
                            String abc = " ";
                            curreno();
                            } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                            }
                            }else{
                            }

                            }
                            });
                        } 
                        catch (NullPointerException e2) {
                            createUserinfo();
                        }
                        } else {
                            showMessage("There was some problem");
                        }
                    }
                });     }

                    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);

 public void open(View view){
                    progress.setMessage("Downloading Music :) ");
                    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
                    progress.show();

                    final int totalProgressTime = 100;

                    final Thread t = new Thread(){

   @Override
   public void run(){

                    int jumpTime = 0;
                    while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime){
                    try {
                    sleep(200);
                    jumpTime += 5;
                    progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    }

                    }
                    };
                    t.start();

                    }
```

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: @PsyDuck thanks for your reply. Actually i want to show user that how many percent loading in done. As soon as server gives me the response my progress bar loading should be dismissed.

Comment: Makes no sense, do you see that anywhere else? Try logging in Facebbok, Gmail or any other site, you never see percentage, unless you're downloading something.

Comment: You can use ProgressDialog while logging in.